# Desabilitar documentação automática web api c#

Tags: c#, api, documentação

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma Api em c#.

Existe uma documentação que ele gera automática conforme imagem a baixo, só que quando eu for subir a API em produção gostaria de desabilitar essa documentação, pois qualquer um que acessar o link raiz da minha api conseguirá ver todas minhas chamadas.

Como consigo desabilitar essa função?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que documentação? Vc diz os links "learn more", "getting started", "get more libraries" e "web hosting"?

Answer (score 0):

Sei que tem um flag que desativa a documentação gerada em XML, espero que ajude.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]